# Sqlite / List of dates for past x calendar days

Tags: sql, sqlite

The following SQLite query provides a list of the past 7 calendar days

```
SELECT Date('now', '-1 days')
UNION
SELECT Date('now', '-2 days')
UNION
SELECT Date('now', '-3 days')
UNION
SELECT Date('now', '-4 days')
UNION
SELECT Date('now', '-5 days')
UNION
SELECT Date('now', '-6 days')
UNION
SELECT Date('now', '-7 days')
```

Result:

```
2021-08-29  
2021-08-30  
2021-08-31  
2021-09-01  
2021-09-02  
2021-09-03  
2021-09-04
```

Can the query be simplified, because I may need many more days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE to get all the integer numbers from 1 to the number of days that you want and then use each of these numbers inside the DATE() function to produce the dates:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 AS d UNION ALL SELECT d + 1 FROM cte WHERE d < ?)
SELECT DATE('now', '-' || d || ' days') AS date
FROM cte;
```

Change `?` to the number of days that you want.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=187e8b344d4e243d51ff1822cbd21e42).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE.  The following includes the current date in the date generation.  You can also clearly extend the duration by changing the `where` clause:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select date('now') as date, 0 as n
      union all
      select date(date, '-1 day'), n + 1
      from cte
      where n < 7
     )
select date
from cte
where n >= 1;
```